# excel macro to read text file and find matches in cells

Tags: vba, excel, match, string-matching

I really could use some help

I have two .txt/csv files that I need to read from into my excel file.

In my excel file I have a whole column, each cell containing string of characters and I need to write a script to be able find matches and and copy an adjacent column from that txt file.

An example of a single row on my txt file is shown below:

"AB101AA","AB10 1AA","AB101A","AB10 1A","AB101","AB10 1","AB10","AB10","AB","10",394251,806376,,
"AB101AF","AB10 1AF","ABERDEEN","ABERDEENSHIRE",,"ABERDEEN, CITY OF"

My excel file would have a cell which probably say "AB101AF" and i want the corresponding cell to run through a million rows and find the match and then find the corresponding nth cell on the txt file and return it on the excel spreadsheet example "ABERDEEN, CITY OF".

I know I havent been helpful in explaining the issue. But any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: where is the code throwing errors?

Comment: If this a million row table, with UK postcodes as it seems, I'd much rather pull the csv data into a 'proper' database, then worry about the query.

Comment: '
'Sub test()
'Dim fn As String, x, i As Long, r As Range
'fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\part_1.txt"
'x = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
'
'For Each r In Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
'For i = 0 To UBound(x)
'If x(i) Like "*" & r.Value & "*" Then
'
'On Error Resume Next
'
'r(, 2).Value = Replace(Split(x(i), vbTab)(6), """", "")
'On Error GoTo 0
'
'Exit For
'End If
'Next
'Next
'End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the size of your text file you could import the file using the GetExternalData option in Excel. This would allow you to load your data into a different Sheet and then use a lookup to your data from the main Sheet. Using Match and/or vlookup should help here.

You could also add a workbook connection to the text file and search using the connection.